# css background-size: cover issue in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility, css

I have this one-page running here: [www.zencak.cz/photo.html](http://www.zencak.cz/photo.html). After several hours trying different solutions I have found on internet I still have compatibility issue with `background-size: cover` in IE9 and older. It works perfectly in Safari (my main browser, Chrome, IE10).

I know this feature is not supported in IE8 and older but for me it works correctly only in IE10 (testing via http://browsershots.org).

I do not post sample code here because it would be tool long - in contrast to simple issue "how to stretch my background image" I generate grid layout from images using some simple JQuery routines.

I tried:

- http://github.com/louisremi/jquery.backgroundSize.js
- http://github.com/aramkocharyan/CSS-Background-Size-jQuery-Plugin
- AlphaImageLoader like - [CSS3 Internet Explorer Scale Background filter:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286239/css3-internet-explorer-scale-background-filter)

looking forward for any help...

Answer (score 0):

[https://github.com/pakcheong/jqthumb](https://github.com/pakcheong/jQThumb) is another plugin that might help. This plugin was built to resolve background-cover issue in IE6, IE7 and IE8.